# Customize delimiter in cite

Tags: biblatex, citing, delimiters

I am using `\parentcites` to generate secondary citations.

```
%!TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa]{biblatex}

%\renewcommand{\compcitedelim}{\multicitedelim}

%\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
  @book{Pia75,
    author = {Piaget, Jean},
    title = {L'équilibration des strustures cognitives},
    publisher = {Presses Universitaires de France},
    year = {1975}
  }

  @incollection{Pia1975,
    author         = {Piaget, Jean},
    booktitle      = {The Process of Child Development},
    publisher      = {{Jason Aronson}},
    editor         = {Neubauer, P. B.},
    title          = {Piaget's theory},
    year           = {1975}
  }

  @incollection{Du91,
    author = {Dubinsky, Ed},
    title = {Reflective Abstraction in Advanced Mathematical Thinking},
    booktitle = {Advanced Mathematical Thinking},
    editor = {Tall, David},
    publisher = {Dordrecht: Kluwer},
    year = {1991},
    options = {skipbib=true}
  }
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\parencites{Pia75}[as cited in][]{Du91}

\parencites{Pia1975}[as cited in][]{Du91}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This works without problems. The detail is that the new APA standards in Spanish require that the delimiter indicated with the arrow be a comma instead of the semicolon. How do I modify this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify `\multicitedelim` as follows

```
\renewcommand*{\multicitedelim}{\addcomma\space}}
```

but if you want this only for secondary citations, you probably want to pack that up in a new command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa]{biblatex}

\newcommand*{\secondaryparencites}{%
  \AtNextMultiCite{%
    \renewcommand*{\multicitedelim}{\addcomma\space}}%
  \parencites}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Pia75,
  author = {Piaget, Jean},
  title = {L'équilibration des strustures cognitives},
  publisher = {Presses Universitaires de France},
  year = {1975}
}
@incollection{Pia1975,
  author         = {Piaget, Jean},
  booktitle      = {The Process of Child Development},
  publisher      = {{Jason Aronson}},
  editor         = {Neubauer, P. B.},
  title          = {Piaget's theory},
  year           = {1975},
}
@incollection{Du91,
  author = {Dubinsky, Ed},
  title = {Reflective Abstraction in Advanced Mathematical Thinking},
  booktitle = {Advanced Mathematical Thinking},
  editor = {Tall, David},
  publisher = {Dordrecht: Kluwer},
  year = {1991},
  options = {skipbib=true}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\secondaryparencites{Pia75}[as cited in][]{Du91}

\secondaryparencites{Pia1975}[as cited in][]{Du91}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: (Piaget, 1975a, as cited in Dubinsky, 1991) (Piaget, 1975b, as cited in Dubinsky, 1991)]

Comment: Works perfectly, Thank you.