# How can I use short-note form for related citations with biblatex-chicago?

Tags: citing, biblatex-chicago

I'm trying out using LaTeX to write a paper in the humanities, and while it generally works well, the one part I'm having trouble with is with citations to one source quoting another source. Since I don't have access to the original, I'm forced to cite the secondary source as quoting the primary source.

To see the formatting issue, here's a MRE:

```
@book{Skinner2022,
    address = {Bloomington},
    title = {Beethoven in {Russia}: {Music} and {Politics}},
    shorttitle = {Beethoven in Russia},
    isbn = {978-0-253-06306-9},
    urldate = {2024-02-16},
    publisher = {Indiana University Press},
    author = {Skinner, Frederick W.},
    year = {2022},
}

@book{Gorky1952,
    title = {Sobranie Sochinenii}, % Not original title!
    language = {Russian},
    author = {Gorky, Maxim},
    volume = {17},
    address = {Moscow},
    publisher = {AN SSSR},
    year = {1952},
    related = {Skinner2022},
    options = {related=true},
    relatedstring = {quoted in},
}

@article{Kedrov1920,
    title = {Lenin i Betkhoven},
    language = {Russian},
    author = {Kedrov, Mikhail},
    journal = {Izvestiia Arkhangel'skogo gubrebkoma i Arkhgubkoma RKP(b)},
    year = 1920,
    related = {Skinner2022},
    options = {related=true},
    relatedstring = {quoted in},
}
```

```tex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes, ellipsis}

\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage[notes, isbn=false, backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}

\renewcommand{\bibsetup}{\singlespacing}
\renewcommand{\bibitemsep}{1\baselineskip}
\renewcommand{\bibhang}{0.5in}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{quote}{\singlespacing}

\addbibresource{bibliography.bib} % Your bibliography file

\title{Title}
\author{First Last}
\date{15 March 2024}

\begin{document}
    \clearpage\maketitle
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    
    \doublespacing

    Quote. \autocite[39--40]{Gorky1952} Reference to main text. \autocite[150]{Skinner2022} Short note reference. \autocite[152]{Skinner2022} Another reference to quoted text. \autocite{Kedrov1920}
    
    \renewcommand{\refname}{Works Cited}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The first citation is okay, but the second citation is the 2nd footnote to the Skinner book, so that should be in short note format, but that isn't the end of the world. The main problem I have is with the last citation where it goes back to using long-note format for Skinner. Ideally, what I would like to see is:

`citation for primary source`, quoted in Skinner *Beethoven in Russia*.

Is there a way to do this? Also, since I'm already asking, is there a way to use \autocite[]{} to reference a specific page number for the 'quoted in' source, not the original source?

Comment: Hmm, this appears to be tricky. For one we would have to tell the `related` feature to switch between long and short forms of citations, which it doesn't do at the moment. Things are made more complicated by the fact that for the `related` feature entries are copied completely, so your `.bbl` contains two versions of `Skinner2022`: the only you explicitly cite and the copy for the related feature. So even if we could switch between short and long, that wouldn't help a lot because `biblatex` works with two different entries with the same data...

Comment: If you don't need the "quoted in" mention in the bibliography, it might be an option to completely get rid of the `related` feature here and use multicite commands to mark secondary citations (shown very roughly in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/711558/35864).